# Very simple Cash with loops

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to create a cash register program that prompts for the amount of items, and then based on the amount of items, prompt for a price for each individual one, and then tally the total. I have a hard time grasping how to use a 'while' loop to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is what i have now: I understand that it creates an infinite loop

```
var itemTotal = prompt("Please enter the amount of items that you're purchasing.");

items = parseInt(itemTotal)

var i = 0;

while(i = items) {

    prompt ("Enter your item price here.");

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework that requires the use of a while loop?  I'd probably use a for loop.

Comment: Maybe a tutorial is the best answer in this case. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Comment: It may also be a 'for' loop. Perhaps this website is not for me because I really do not know what I am doing and I have not yet had my coding epiphany.

Comment: Which website are you using to learn coding?

Answer (score 0):

You want the expression in the while loop to be true while you want it to loop.  In this case you want `i` to be less than `items`

```
while ( i < items ) {
    /* get cost */
    /* add cost to total */
    i++;
}
```

I forgot to point out that `i = items` will assign the value of `items` to `i`.  To check if `i` is equal to `items` you need to use `i == items`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of items (from your user prompt) why don't use use a for loop? Either will work, but I think a for loop would be more readable.

```
for (i=1; i <= NUM_FROM_PROMPT; i++) {
    //do something here
}
```

with a while loop it is

```
i=1 //starting point
while (i <= NUM_FROM_PROMPT) {
    //do something here
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I try to get what you want:

```
var total = parseInt(prompt("How much items total?", "0"));

var price = 0;
for (var i = 0;i<total.length;i++) {
    var individualPrice = prompt("How much does item " + (i+1) + " cost?", 0);
    price+=parseInt(individualPrice);
}
alert("Total Price is " + price);
```

Hope that helps. Even if it may be your homework.

Comment: It is homework, but I was utterly lost. Thank you so much. I'm still going to code it my way from what i've learned

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

In that documentation link, they have an example that looks like this.

```
n = 0;
x = 0;
while (n < 3) {
  n ++;
  x += n;
}
```

so you can use this as a guide for your cash register program.

```
//get user input for number of items
var num_of_items = prompt("How many items?");
var n = 0;
var total = 0;

while (n < num_of_items) {
  n ++;

  //get cost of item
  var cost_of_item = 0;

   cost_of_item = parseInt(prompt("Cost of item"));

  total = total + cost_of_item;

}
alert("total price: " + total);
​
```

I'm not sure how you are handling user input, so I've left that for you to figure out :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/LEdbm/3/

Comment: oooh ok, you're comments have shown me the way. :) I really really appreciate it the help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemTotal = Number(prompt("Please enter the amount of items that you're purchasing."));
var priceTotal = 0

while(itemTotal) {
    priceTotal += Number(prompt("Enter your item price here."));
    itemTotal--;
}

alert("Please pay " + priceTotal);
```

​

Comment: You might want to clarify what `while(itemTotal)` is doing since the OP is a beginner.

Comment: Also, it could be written more elegantly as `while(itemTotal--)`